# Chrome and Opera fail absolute positioning using jQuery's method .css()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have coded a dropdown menu using jQuery. The goal is to display a sub-menu when a navigation item is clicked. The jQuery script applies a `style="position: absolute;"` to the corresponding sub-menu in order to not make the other navigation items move over.

But Chrome and Opera don't apply the absolute positioning. Or they do after a click anywhere on the page. It works fine with Safari and Firefox.

You can have a look at the whole thing [on this page](http://louisfisch.github.io/Headery/demo.html)
All files are hosted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/louisfisch/Headery)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably coming from the succession of `.css("display", "block")` and `.css("position", "absolute")`. I found a way to get the height of an element containing an absolute positioned child. So the problem is fixed. I updated the code [here](https://github.com/louisfisch/Headery).

Answer (score 0):

Change `.css({position: "absolute"});` to `.css("position", "absolute");`

The following sample works fine on all browsers:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#setPos').click(function(){
    $('#myDiv').css("position", "absolute");
    $('#myDiv').css("left", "100px");
    $('#myDiv').css("top", "20px");
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
<input id='setPos' type='button' value='absolute' />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I committed the changes so you can see it by yourself. What is really weird is that after a click anywhere on the page the absolute positioning takes effect. I can't figure out why.